# How to read only final version from multiple commits?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

When you check someone else's commits most of the time you read code parts  that changed on next commits but still you need to read old versions. what I mean is

first commit

`function a(){
      //some wrong code

}`

second commit

`function b(){
   //fixed code
}`

User fixed his code already on next commit but I have to read this code part twice which is time consuming. How can I read only final version of files from multiple commits instead going through all commits ?

Comment: Is [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) the answer?

Comment: If you're using an IDE like IntelliJ, there is a nice Git plugin which lets you diff any file against any revision in a branch, or against any other branch.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check someone's code is to use a Pull Request in a review environment (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) and [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request)) that lets the other person organize their work, lets you make comments in appropriate places, and lets you browse the changes to see exactly how things have changed.

A rich environment like that is quite valuable for reading code & providing feedback.

Failing that, or if you want to be more thorough in your review, there are lots of different command-line commands that will let you browse the changes between various versions (`git diff` and `git log -u`), see which files have changed (`git log --stat`), try running code at various previous versions (`git checkout`), and so on.  It's well worth getting familiar with these tools - don't get discouraged if you can't "learn everything" about them right away, there are lots and lots of options to most Git commands, and you can get by for 95% of your work by knowing just a few common ones.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone/pull from remote to local repo, the branch always point to the final version, you can view directly.

If you want to view the code from earlier versions, you use to use `git checkout <commit>`.

And if you want compare the final version from an earlier version, you can use `git diff <commit>..branchname` (such as `git diff e48ff..master`).